# How to correctly embed another language into my current language defintion?

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, smalltalk

I have [Smalltalk sublime-syntax file (YAML)](https://bitbucket.org/-tukanos-/sublime-highlighting-for-smalltalk-x/src/default/Smalltalk.sublime-syntax) for Sublime Text 3 and I would like to add an highlighting support for embedded C code.

The `inline C` (which always starts with `^%\{` and ends with `%\}$`) code among the smalltalk code.

A simple example (not much `C` but wanted a simple case):

```
sigABRT
    "return the signal number for SIGABRT - 0 if not supported by OS
     (the numeric value is not the same across unix-systems)"

%{  /* NOCONTEXT */
#ifdef SIGABRT
    RETURN ( __mkSmallInteger(SIGABRT) );
#else
    RETURN ( __mkSmallInteger(0) );
#endif
%}
!
```

There is new feature `embed` in Sublime text (with even an [example](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/commit/72bd6bdae9e185d9ebedab9679a55cd8ae8c3e60)).

I tried to do something like this:

```
- match: '^%\{'
  embed: scope:source.c
  embed_scope: meta.environment.embedded.c.smalltalk source.c.embedded
  escape: '%\}$'
```

However, I was unable to correctly incorporate it into my [current highlighting file](https://bitbucket.org/-tukanos-/sublime-highlighting-for-smalltalk-x/src/default/Smalltalk.sublime-syntax).

Does anyone know how to correctly embed one language to another?

Comment: Stop adding unrelated tags. this is clearly not about the C language, but how to configure the editor.

Comment: @Olaf Did you read the question? It is about syntax highlighting of C language which is embedded in Smalltalk, yes in Sublime text editor.  How can C language highlighting be unrelated to C?

Comment: Because it's irrelevant which language it is. Could as well be Brainfuck, it's a question about how to configure the editor to mixc two highlighting styles in the same source code. I strongly doubt you intend to completely write your own hightlighting file. Even then it's disputable whether the C tag is relevant.

Comment: We already have a backlog of tags to burn, please refrain from adding more unnecessary. Starting your own tag just for this question does not make sense. Less, as you did not add some info what the tag is about and how to use it. If that was to be more specific: it won't help, you already tagged smalltalk and sublime, everyone knowing enough to possibly help will know what you mean.

Comment: @Olaf First -  I have added information about Smalltalk/X tag, but it needs to be approved by some that has enough reputation to do so. You should check before writing "..you did not add some info what the tag...".   The tag `smalltak-x` will be used in my future questions as it has some rather specific features among Smalltalk environments; your removal does not make sense.  Second - it could be Brainfuck, but it is not it is C so the tag is not irrelevant (I would tag it Brainfuck). On the other hand, you are right about that this could be meant as a guide for someone with similar needs.

Comment: @Olaf Out of curiosity, if it is irrelevant what language it is why you left the smalltalk tag? (To understand your algorithm). I hope I don't have to rewrite the information about `smalltalk-x`.

Comment: _sigh_ Because I trusted you the code is some kind of smalltalk. That's an established tag. Read my previous comment carefully and completely again.

Comment: @Olaf Ok.  The last point.  The code is Smalltalk and Inline C which is unique in Smalltalk world.  I don't know any other Smalltalk implementation where you see/work with the C code directly from the environment.  Thank you for sharing your view. Have a nice day/night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a little sticky because you've provided a sample syntax definition and a sample of some Smalltalk source code, but the code provided is not highlighted by the provided syntax because it's not structured properly.

For our purposes here, lets assume that the Smalltalk sample you provided is the following one. This may or may not be valid (it's been a long time since I've worked with Smalltalk) but it highlights with your syntax, so lets call that good enough for testing purposes.

```smalltalk
Object subclass: Test [
    sigABRT
        "return the signal number for SIGABRT - 0 if not supported by OS
         (the numeric value is not the same across unix-systems)"

    %{  /* NOCONTEXT */
    #ifdef SIGABRT
        RETURN ( __mkSmallInteger(SIGABRT) );
    #else
        RETURN ( __mkSmallInteger(0) );
    #endif
    %}
    !
].
```

The syntax match that you provided above is the correct one to use, so I'm guessing that your problem is in where you placed it in the syntax.

So lets presume that there is more than one place where we might want to match one of these C blocks in the syntax definition; in that case we may want to create a new `context` in the syntax that contains the match so that we can `include` it where it's needed:

```yaml
c-block:
  - match: '%\{'
    embed: scope:source.c
    embed_scope: meta.environment.embedded.c.smalltalk source.c.embedded
    escape: '%\}$'
```

This is the same excerpt as you provided above, but placed into a context. So lets say that the first place where a block such as this can appear is in the body of a block. You have a `block-body` context in your syntax, so we stick an `include` onto the end of it to include this new context:

```yaml
block-body:
  - include: pragma
  - include: selector
  - include: literal
  - include: block
  - include: comment
  - include: c-block
```

However, this does not have the desired outcome; the highlight is not correct:

[image: Incorrect Highlighting]

Clearly the highlighting is going wrong starting at least at the C comment start, possibly earlier. If you use `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name` while the cursor is on the comment, you can see that the scope assigned is `source.smalltalk entity.name.function`, which means that the syntax is treating the C comment start as a method name.

It also looks like the `%{` construct is not properly highlighted, and a check shows that the scope of the `%` character is `source.smalltalk keyword.other`.

So in reality the problem currently is that with the above definitions in place, instead of seeing `%{` as starting a C block, it's being seen as a keyword, and if it's a keyword then the rules for matching a C block are not triggering at all.

If you look at your syntax, the `main` context looks like this:

```yaml
main:
  - match: '([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s*(subclass:)\s*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s*\['
    captures:
      1: entity.other.inherited-class
      2: keyword.other
      3: entity.name.type
    push:
      - match: '\]'
        pop: true
      - include: pragma
      - match: '(([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*:)|[+\-\/\\*~<>=@%|&?!.,:;^]+)\s*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)'
        captures:
          1: entity.name.function
          3: variable.other
      - match: "([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)"
        scope: entity.name.function
      - include: block
      - include: comment
      - include: block-body
```

These rules say that when we see a line that starts with something like `BaseClass subclass: SubClass [`, we are entering into an anonymous context (via the `push`) to handle the contents of the class body (or block or whatever).

The anonymous context contains the rule to pop out when it sees the closing `]` character, two different matches to find a function name, then an `include` on the contexts for `block`, `comment` and `block-body` respectively.

When you `include`, Sublime takes all of the `match` rules from that context and inserts a copy of them at the point where you do the insert, as if you had just manually entered them there.

In addition, when there is more than one rule in a `context` that might potentially match, the first `match` rule in the context is the one that is applied (i.e. it "wins" the tie).

The scope `keyword.other` is applied in the rules from the `pragma` context as well as the `selector` context, and the `selector` context can match single `%` character as a keyword.

Thus the problem here is that since the `include c-block` appears after `selector` in the include list for the `block-body` context, the `selector` context is finding and matching the `%` character before the rule for the C block can find it.

The solution then would be to shift the location of the `include c-block` to be prior to that item to make sure that it matches first:

```yaml
block-body:
  - include: c-block
  - include: pragma
  - include: selector
  - include: literal
  - include: block
  - include: comment
```

With that in place, the block highlights more like we would expect:

[image: Correct Highlighting]

Comment: You are right about "... the code provided is not highlighted by the provided syntax because it's not structured properly..." Well that was part of my issue.  I have tagged this also with "Smalltalk-x" (Olaf (now called: "To hones for this site" disagreed and deleted it) which is unique in this matter.  It mixes a Smalltalk code with C (which then generates a mixed code).  Your explanation is perfect and it answers my question.   You have even made me think to fix my faulty `syntax` file.

Comment: I'll improve on the test file & the definition.

Comment: I have now re-created the highlighting file and it works correctly.  Could you perhaps help me with my new question: https://superuser.com/questions/1345947/how-to-remove-a-limit-of-100kb-when-highlighting-a-file-with-custom-syntax ?  I had to post it on superuser as it does not include any programming.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around a similar issue with Regex lookahead and lookbehinds

```yaml
    - match: ' (?=\{")'
      embed: scope:source.json
      escape: '(?<=\})$'
```